Edit pinElement of an advacedMarkerElement without creating a new PinElement
I save all my advancedMarkersElements in an array and I want to change their Pinelements and specifically their glyphcolor with maptypeid_changed event.
I want to keep all the other properties the same.
So, I would like to do something like this
for (var j in markersDB2) 
{
    let mark = markersDB2[j];                
    mark.content.glyphColor = labelColor;
}

But the only way that I found is to create a new PinElement and attach it to the advancedMarkerElement.
But how can I retain the same properties to the new PinElement as the existing ones in the original advanceMarkerElement?
Any idea?

You can store the PinElement in a custom attribute of the marker itself and update it later without creating a new PinElement.  You'd need to adapt it to what you already have, but something like this should work:
//create new marker
var newMarker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
  map: map,
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
  });

//create a new pin
let myPin = new google.maps.marker.PinElement({
  background: "Green",
  glyphColor: "Red"
  });

//save the entire PinElement as a custom element of the marker
newMarker.myPinElement = myPin;     
newMarker.content = myPin.element;      

....
//To update the pin:
//change only the pinelement attributes you need to update
newMarker.myPinElement.glyphColor= "Blue";           
//update the marker
newMarker.content = newMarker.myPinElement.content;   

